# jdo google app engine retrieve by isEmpty

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, jdo

I build application in gwt and I used jdo google app engine
I have this class in jdo

```
class A{
   List<String> list;
}
```

I want to retrieve all object that there list is empty so I write query like this

```
select from A where list.isEmpty()
```

and I get this exception

```
Unsupported method <isEmpty> while parsing expression: InvokeExpression{[PrimaryExpression{list}].isEmpty(<none>)}
```

why I get this exception?
thank you

Answer (score 1):

`isEmpty` is not a valid query filter.  You can test if a list is empty, but `isEmpty` is not a query filter.  That property is not indexed, so cannot be queried.

Comment: but if I go to site http://db.apache.org/jdo/jdoql_methods.html ->
to collection methods table I saw the filter isEmpty exist

Comment: yes, but that only tells you what is available "in theory" should the datastore (and Google's plugin) support it.

Comment: firstly thank you for reply. so what I need to write to retrieve all objects that list is empty? thank you

Comment: 1) you can query all objects, loop through them to test.  2) you can add a new property `count` (which will be indexed), and filter your query by `count==0`.  Each time you write to the object you store the count, or isempty

Comment: ok firstly thank you for reply.
I used method contains() and it works for me and isEmpty() not works.
I saw at the same table the method size() is it also in theory? 
thank you